# Data Base Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database like this:-

```
state_name|district_name|id
jammu     |kupwara      |jk-01
kashmir   |anantnag     |jk-02
```

I want a mysql Query such that when

`statename is selected (jammu), distname should be selected(kupwara) based on thier id`.

If any one knows please help me out.Thanks in Advance

Comment: clearify your question perfectly

Comment: Kindly use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to clarify your problem. You question is not clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, then query should be like this

```
SELECT state_name,district_name from TableName WHERE id='jk-01' //you can have your specific id here
```

Comment: I apologise for my mistake.Any way thanks.I got answer from Sumit Chourasia.Thanks!!